# Detailed balance equations - Markov chains and stationarity

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

> Let $X$ be a Markov chain on state space $S=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ for which $p(n,n+1)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$ and $p(n,n-1)=1-p(n,n+1)$, where $\lambda,\mu$ are positive constants. I want to show that $\pi_n=\frac{(n+\rho)\rho^{n-1}\pi_0}{n!}$ for all $n\ge 1$ where $\rho=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$.

My work: If $\pi$ on $S$ satisfies the detailed balance equations then $\pi_ip_{ij}=\pi_jp_{ji}$ for all $i,j$. In our case I cannot see how to use these equations in order to prove the result. I was thinking of arguing along the lines of an induction but even then it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is $p(0,1)$? Is it 1, or can the system stay dead for a bit?

Comment: What do you mean? @Ian

Comment: Your equations don't make sense at the boundary. We need to know what happens there to do the problem.

Comment: Rather we need that to write the solution in terms of $\pi_0$ and then normalize. You can write $\pi_n$ for $n \geq 1$ in terms of $\pi_1$ as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can show what you're trying to show as written. Ignoring the boundary condition for a moment (Ian is right that what happens at state $0$ is a problem here), consider the case where $\lambda = 1$ and $\mu = 2$, so that $\rho = 1/2$. Then just by examining states $2$ and $3$, we'd have

\begin{align*}
  p(2, 3) &= 1/3 \\
  p(3, 2) &= 2/3 \\
  \pi(2) &= \frac{(2+ \frac 1 2) (\frac 1 2)^1 \pi_0}{2!} = \frac{5}{8} \pi_0 \\
  \pi(3) &= \frac{(3 + \frac 1 2)(\frac 1 2)^2 \pi_0}{3!} = \frac{7}{48} \pi_0
\end{align*}

and these numbers do not satisfy the balance equations.

Or, more simply, consider the case when $\lambda = \mu = 1$; assuming that $0$ is not an absorbing state, this is a null recurrent chain (whereas the above is positive recurrent) with $p(n, n+1) = p(n, n-1) = 1/2$. Any distribution satisfying the balance equations must have $\pi(2) = \pi(3)$, but it won't.